# How to efficiently do complex threshold in RGB image using opencv?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I want to translate a matlab code into c++ opencv, it threshold a RGB image: red value>threshold1 AND red/green>threshold2 AND red/blue>threshold3

The matlab code is:

```
bw=(im(:,:,1)>=red_th&(im(:,:,1)./im(:,:,2))>=red_green_th&(im(:,:,1)./im(:,:,3))>=red_blue_th);
```

Where `im(:,:,1), im(:,:,2)` and `im(:,:,3)` is the r, g, b value respectively.

I found the matlab code is very efficient comparing with looping all pixels using "for cols and for rows". Hence, I want to find similar efficient method in opencv instead of looping cols and rows.

I read some information about `cv::threshold and inRange`, however, it seems that they cannot satisfy my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this directly with `threshold` or `inRange`, but you can easily convert this to OpenCV first splitting the 3 channels, and then using Matrix Expressions:

```
Mat im = ...
vector<Mat> planes;
split(im, planes); // B, G, R planes

Mat bw = (planes[2] >= red_th) & 
         (planes[2] / planes[1] >= red_green_th) &
         (planes[2] / planes[0] >= red_blue_th);
```

Since Matlab usually works on doubles, you'd better convert the OpenCV matrices to double (unless they are already so):

```
Mat im = ...
vector<Mat> planes;
split(im, planes); // B, G, R planes

for(size_t i=0; i<planes.size(); ++i) {
    planes[i].convertTo(planes[i], CV_64F);
}

Mat bw = (planes[2] >= red_th) & 
         (planes[2] / planes[1] >= red_green_th) &
         (planes[2] / planes[0] >= red_blue_th);
```

Or you can for loops, which can be very fast if you work on pointers (I'm assuming your `im` is of type `CV_8UC3`):

```
Mat3b im = ...
Mat1b bw(im.rows, im.cols, uchar(0));

int rows = im.rows;
int cols = im.cols;
if(im.isContinuous()) {
    cols = rows * cols;
    rows = 1;
}

for(int r=0; r<rows; ++r) {
    Vec3b* ptr_im = im.ptr<Vec3b>(r);
    uchar* ptr_bw = bw.ptr<uchar>(r)
    for(int c=0; c<cols; ++c) { 
        const Vec3b& bgr = ptr_im[c];

        // Take care of division by 0  

        ptr_bw[c] = (bgr[2] >= red_th) &&
                    (bgr[2] / bgr[1] >= red_green_th) &&
                    (bgr[2] / bgr[0] >= red_blue_th);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you have some issue with the type. Matrices in Matlab are usually of type double, while in OpenCV they are likely to be of type `uchar`. If it's a problem integer division, you need to convert the OpenCV matrices to double before that

Comment: Just an update. The second point solution works by just avoiding dividing 0. ptr_bw[c] = (bgr[2]>=red_th)&&(bgr[1]==0||(bgr[2]/bgr[1]>=red_green_th))&&(bgr[0]==0||(bgr[2]/bgr[0]>=red_blue_th));   bw = bw*255;  However, the first split solution doesn't work well, the result is wrong (it is much different with the result of matlab code).  It seems that (planes[2]/planes[0]) has some problem. I am not sure if it is the datatype issue. Do you know Why?

Comment: I tried the new split code, it still has some problem. Anyway, the second point solution works very well and fast.